# "sql-insert" and "sql-update" were recently made synonyms of "sql"

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonym-process

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/synonyms

I think this is wrong and should be reverted. I have been using these tags to both tag and search in the past and would like to keep using them. IMO, [sql-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-select) is an acceptable synonym, but [sql-insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-insert) or [sql-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-update) are not.

I tried to revert the error, but did not find a way. Seems like this is not in my power.

Please assist if you agree.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I agree that these are not good synonyms on the [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) tag. I've removed both of them ([sql-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-update) and [sql-insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-insert)).  While they are SQL related, they should be separate tags.

Comment: That was fast! Kudos.