# Tag could not be added

Tags: support, tags

I am trying to add `sql-insert` tag to this question:

*[Insert data into table with values inside quotes of another select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40986620/insert-data-into-table-with-values-inside-quotes-of-another-select-statement)*

But it is not adding to the question. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a synonym of [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql), which already exists on the question: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/synonyms

Comment: Good to know. Why the other tags in synonyms list are not showing in tag suggestion itself except `sql-insert`

Comment: While investigating this to add my own answer that you ninja'd, I noticed that [sql-insert] (unlike most synonyms) not only shows up in the auto-complete list separately, but claims to have some 1800 questions of its own, as opposed to [sql]'s hundreds of thousands. Any particular reason it got wedged in this non-standard state?

Comment: @NathanTuggy Looks like it only got synonymized, and not merged with the master tag. I don't know why - my money would be on some sort of oversight. A moderator can merge them if the community here agrees (or I can upon a closer review and some asking around tomorrow).

Comment: @Prdp See my comment to Nathan above.

Comment: @Prdp Just FYI, I asked around, and we ended up removing the synonym for similar reasons as the ones described [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288715/sql-insert-and-sql-update-were-recently-made-synonyms-of-sql). If you want, you should be able to add [sql-insert] to that question now.