# Burninate [javax] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

The [javax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javax) tag has the wiki:

> Pointless catch-all tag. Do not use. For removal.

It has 23 followers, and 199 questions.
If its meaning should be `javax` package of `java` I do not see how such tag would be helpful.

So it should be burninated?

---

Edit:
Package `javax` contains various unrelated things from ui, to security so it is ambiguous and adds nothing to question.
In most cases there is specific tag to use:

- [swing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info) for Swing UI framework
- [javamail/javax.mail](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javamail/info) for java mail API
- [bean-validation](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bean-validation/info) for javax.validation
- [jaxp](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jaxp/info), [jax-ws](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jax-ws/info) and other ...

Existing questions should use specific tag, or `javax` tag could be just removed in cases where it is already tagged with `java` and other on topic tag: `mail`, `validation`, ...

**Edit**

I was convinced by anwers to [make it synonym instead!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367505/synonymize-javax-to-java)

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Java, but isn't it more reasonable to just merge Java and javax, and create a synonym? A burninate requires a lot of effort, and I'm not sure that's appropriate here. Note that this excerpt is set by a single user, and might not reflect community opinion

Comment: @Luuklag other way around; first number is the 'score', i.e. amount of upvotes, second is the amount of posts (questions or answers). There are 3 persons who answered 2 questions, everyone else has 1 post (either answer or question), so I don't think they'll be of much help.

Comment: @Adriaan, you are right. Bless good table headers....

Comment: What about: `java-javax`

Comment: I edited my question to point to ambiguity of `javax` package

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth `javax` is just a namespace, containing lot of java related stuff (And that stuff is unrelated to each other). It is not synonym for `java`. Most of time there is specific feature people are asking about, see my updated question.

Comment: @Piro if anything, being a synonym will prevent people from tagging questions with it (it will automatically become "java" when entered) and will force them to look for a more specific tag if they have some specific feature in mind.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev you have a very optimistic views of the capabilities of the people using tags https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339068/792066

Comment: @Braiam that question is from 2 years ago. Now the only way to add  a tag is to select one of the options from the popup, or press Enter only if there is no popup (i.e. no existing options) and confirm new tag creation. If you type a synonym, the canonical name is presented in the popup. The popup is very nontrivial to dismiss, you need to go out of your way to get around it, so you can only blame yourself if you do that and get an error.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev remember that more recent questions with negative score and closed as duplicated gets deleted. That that was the one I found to show you doesn't mean that there are none more recent, yet it proves that it happens.

Comment: What about adding the [javax] tag to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28894914/are-classes-and-metodes-in-the-javax-packege-static-or-not ?

Comment: @Cœur too late, `javax` is already synonym of `java`. And it makes no sense asking about whole javax package anyway. Also it seems OP is more interested in [tag:swing] just did not state that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`javax` (Java eXtension) is the namespace that was historically used for everything in Java standard library that was not considered its "core", for various reasons.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727844/javax-vs-java-package)

So, it effectively means "Java standard library".
For SO purposes, this means the same as [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) because it gives the same information to a reader:

- `javax` is an integral part of any Java installation, it's present whenever Java is present. So, it carries no information about what you actually have available beside [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java): a tag about the specific Java version and flavor is needed for that.
- The namespace is large and amorphous, so the tag gives no information about what functionality from it you have in mind (again, beside the fact it is [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)), you'll have to be more specific for anyone to be able to help you.

So, they tag shouldn't be burninated but rather **synonymized to [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).**

By the way [Wikipedia also redirects "javax" to Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Javax&redirect=no).

Comment: I can't respond to that, since I am not that aware of practices for synonyms. While you are right (about effects), is it what should be done? Are there other tags that are made synonymous in similar matter?

Comment: @Piro Added a more thorough justification. At SE, the "practice" is whatever the community agrees upon. Your job here is to vote if you (dis)agree with the post and mark it as accepted if you think it resolves the matter. Since this is a [meta-tag:burninate-request], to actually propose synonymization, it's best to create a separate [meta-tag:synonym-request].

Comment: Yeah, @Piro, the SE community has the head-scratching custom of [rolling over experts whenever it fits them.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339101/792066)

Comment: In the end I was convinced that it should be synonym and created [synonym request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367505/synonymize-javax-to-java)

Comment: This answer is not correct, there are also libraries in the `javax`-namespace that are not part of the Java standard library, but - for example - of Java Enterprise Edition, or other - separate - extension libraries.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel that either falls under the explanation (JavaEE is one of the "flavors") or doesn't change anything.