# Synonymize [javax] to [java]

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

Following my [Burninate [javax] tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366294/burninate-javax-tag) I was convinced that [javax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javax) should be synonym of [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) instead. Citation from [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366363/1651107):

> [`javax` (Java eXtension) is the namespace that was historically used
>   for everything in Java standard library that was not considered its
>   "core", for various reasons.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727844/javax-vs-java-package)
>
> So, it effectively means "Java standard library".   For SO purposes,
>   this means the same as [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) because it gives the same
>   information to a reader:
>
> - `javax` is an integral part of any Java installation, it's present whenever Java is present. So, it carries no information about what you
>     actually have available beside [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java): a tag about the specific
>     Java version and flavor is needed for that.
> - The namespace is large and amorphous, so the tag gives no information about what functionality from it you have in mind (again,
>     beside the fact it is [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)), you'll have to be more specific for
>     anyone to be able to help you.
>
> So, they tag shouldn't be burninated but rather **synonymized to
>   [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).**
>
> By the way [Wikipedia also redirects "javax" to Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Javax&redirect=no).

What convinced me was looking at [Synonyms of java](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/synonyms) where there is a lot of what I would call "onesided" synonyms like [jre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jre), [openjdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openjdk).

Comment: That answer is not correct, there are also libraries in the `javax`-namespace that are not part of the Java standard library, but - for example - of Java Enterprise Edition, or other - separate - extension libraries. In other words, `javax` is a lot broader than just standard Java, and I don't think it should be a synonym.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[javax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javax) is now synonymized.
Just to counter @MarkRotteveel, while it is truth that [javax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javax) does not directly indicate [java-se](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-se), this is also not the case of [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) itself.

Tag [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) is used often simply as a Java language tag regardless of platform - [java-se](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-se), [java-ee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee), or other. 
For example [this search for java tag, servlets, without java-ee tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+-%5Bjava-ee%5D+servlet).
Questions related to web frameworks (like [vaadin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vaadin) or [gwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gwt)) use mostly [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) while being based on [java-ee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-ee) platform.

Comment: That’s a strange comparison. `[java]` is the tag for the *programming language* and whether you’re using SE or EE, you are still programming in Java. There is no programming language named “javax”, so the way, the language tag `[java]` is used, does not allow conclusion how the package prefix tag `[javax]` should be used. The package prefix `javax` is as meaningless as the package prefix `com` or `org`, there’s plenty of unrelated actual packages with the same prefix. Now, with the synonym, the issue of `javax` being unspecific is solved by replacing the tag with even more unspecific `java`.

Answer (score 3):

The `javax`-namespace is a lot broader than standard Java: besides the `javax.*` package in Java, it includes all of Java EE specification libraries, and some other extensions not included in Java. So, synonymizing for that reason is not the right way.

I'd suggest that a new request for burnination should be made + maybe a blacklisting, as the tag itself adds no relevant information to a question.

Comment: Are there specific Java EE technologies which are narrow enough to fit by themselves under [tag:javax] but not broad enough to fit under their own tab?

Comment: @Makoto No, that doesn't work. The `javax` namespace contains things ranging from JDBC datasources to imageprocessing, from security to XML serialization, from enterprise resource connectors to sending mail and a lot of stuff in between. The amorphousness of this is to me the very reason why it should just go away.

Comment: My question there would be, are *those* topics then covered by more specific tags?  You're not selling me (yet) on the fact that javax as a tag should stick around if it's truly incorporating all of those aspects.

Comment: @Makoto Where am I suggesting this tag should stick around? In fact I'm suggesting that it should be burninated as originally requested, and maybe even blacklisted.

Comment: As argument against synonymization, I understand from this answer that `javax` = [tag:java] + [tag:java-ee] + more stuff.

Comment: Hmm.  So perhaps a burnination would be needed to clean the tag up.  It's tiny, too - under 500 - so a handful of us _could_ do it.  I see the light now; feel encouraged to downvote the synonym request and repost the burnination request.

Comment: @Cœur No. For example package `javax.sql` is plain normal Java, package `javax.mail` is either java + JavaMail, or maybe Java EE (Java Mail is available separately and as part of Java EE), javax.transaction is partially in Java, partially in Java EE, etc. There can be no specific meaning derived from tagging `javax` (except maybe if you are interested in the concept and history of the `javax`-namespace, but that would be very much off topic).

Comment: @Cœur The only meaning that can be derived from javax tag is that you are using java with packages from javax namespace (and that is partially core of java and partially some additional stuff)

Comment: As I explained in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366294/burninate-javax-tag/366363#366363 , [tag:javax] gives exactly the same information for the purposes of SO as [tag:java]. That's the reason why synonymization as opposed to burnination was suggested in the first place.