# Update roomba help page with changes for duplicate questions

Tags: feature-request, help-center, automatic-deletion

[I've heard recently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366294/burninate-javax-tag#comment576815_366294) that quesitons closed as a duplicate are now being deleted in some cases, too. [Are questions closed as duplicates ever automatically deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193798/are-questions-closed-as-duplicates-ever-automatically-deleted) hints as much, too.

If that's the case, https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba needs be updated with that info unless there's some ulterior motive to keep it secret from the general public.

Comment: The Roomba page says in the first part: "If the question is more than 30 days old, and ... has −1 or lower score,
has no answers,
is not locked." I've always understood this to mean after a month, if the unanswered duplicate isn't useful enough for someone to have upvoted it, it gets trashed. Though I might be understanding it wrong, I never really paid too much attention to it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Some* duplicates are automatically deleted but not because they are duplicates. They are deleted when they meet either of the following sets of conditions, which are stated on the Help Center page:

#### Set #1

> the question is more than 30 days old, and
>   has −1 or lower score
>   has no answers
>   is not locked

#### Set #2

> the question is more than 365 days old, and
>   has a score of 0 or less, or a score of 1 and a deleted owner
>   has no answers
>   is not locked
>   has view count <= the age of the question in days times 1.5
>   has 1 or 0 comments
>   isn't on a meta site

There is no automatic deletion rule that is specific to duplicates.

By intersecting conditions between set 1 and set 2, we notice that if the question has answers, it will not be deleted (it is a frequent source of confusion)