# Why do people delete-vote questions that are eligible for roomba?

Tags: support, vote-to-delete, automatic-deletion

Looking through posts with pending delete votes in [moderation tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools), I notice that a noticeable share of them are eligible for automatic deletion. E.g. today, there were two such questions:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51672453/how-to-get-meta-data-from-maria-db-in-java
- [Error function not defined javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51597405/error-function-not-defined-javascript)

What's the purpose of going for the trouble of visiting and voting on the post, using a limited vote (and making other people do the same) if the automatic mechanism will take care of it anyway?

Comment: Vote often, vote early.

Comment: Not sure - they cannot abide looking at the Q. any longer and are trying to save other users from the same pain?

Comment: Because sometimes answers are upvoted or accepted and thus the question gets protected from the mighty roomba?

Comment: @yivi I take your 'sometimes' and raise you a 'frequently'.

Comment: @HansPassant [not a year, just 30 days](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba).  [I made that mistake, too](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367653/update-roomba-help-page-with-changes-for-duplicate-questions).

Comment: Because *nuking them from orbit is the only way to be sure!*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why do people delete-vote questions that are eligible for roomba?

This person because it is a lot easier to click once than to work out how the roomba rules are going to treat the Q.

Comment: They should use an userscript https://github.com/makyen/StackExchange-userscripts/tree/master/Roomba-Forecaster

Comment: So, you have so many delete votes that you no longer worry about spending an extra few? I did run out due to these questions a few times.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I can imagine not everyone religiously uses up delete votes such that they have to ration them.